# SQL LAG function

Tags: sql, lag

I tried using the LAG function to calculate the value of previous weeks, but there are gaps in the data due to the fact that certain weeks are missing.

This is the table:

[image: Table as of now]

The problem is that the LAG functions takes the previous found week in the table. But I would like it to be zero if the previous week is not consecutive previous week.

This is what I would like it to be:

[image: What I would like it to be]

I'm open to any solutions.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And I'm lost on the ordering.  Please explain how the data is ordered (presumably the first column) and what the column means.  Your sample code would also help.

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this is by having some sort of a Calendar dimension that you link your data to. You will have the week numbers in the calendar, regardless of whether or not you have transactional data for that particular week.

Answer (score 0):

Your example data is baffling.  You have multiple rows per time frame.  The first column looks like a string, which doesn't really make sense for the comparison.

So, let me answer based on a simpler data mode.  The answer is to use `range`.  If you had an integer column that specified the time frame:

```
ordering     sales
    1         10
    2         20
    3         30
    5         50
```

Then you would phrase this as:

```
select max(sales) over (order by ordering range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding)
```

This would return the value from the "previous" row as defined by the first column.  The value would be in a separate *column*, not a separate *row*.